# React (Nextjs) lib that resizes and crop image

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I need a lib for react that takes an image (ex. 500w by 1000h following the baviour of `object-fit: cover`) and crops it to 256w by 144h
automaticly and serves it back to use at base64 format. English isn't my native language but I tried my best looking for this and only found libs that allow users to manually crop the image – I need an automatic procedure.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried many libraries and the one that works best for me is [smartcrop](https://www.npmjs.com/package/smartcrop)

It is very customizable (the most customizable I found).

You don't need NextJS to use it, you can use a simple node script.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I'm trying to implement this but I keep on getting TypeError for the file I'm attaching, it is basically the direct file (e.target.files[0]), it is not undefined or something, what should I do? tried aswell to give the function data image url but it doesnt work